# Получить взаимно однозначное соответствие интервала (0;1) и точек на нескольких дугах окружности

Tags: unity3d

Имеем несколько окружностей. На одной выбранной окружности необходимо выбрать случайную точку, такую, что эта точка лежит вне всех других окружностей. Используем Unity. Сейчас используется тупое решение: Берем случайную точку на окружности (Random.insideUnitCircle.normalized) раз за разом, пока эта точка не удовлетворит условию.
Это ужасно медленно, не говоря уже о том, что случаются ситуации, когда вся окружность так или иначе лежит в нескольких других окружностях.

Предлагаю следующее: Найти все дуги окружности, лежащие вне других, как пары точек по часовой стрелке(посильная задача), и описать функцию, которая по числу от 0 до 1 включительно будет выдавать одну из этих точек на окружности. В нахождении этой функции проблема, и я прошу помощи. Если есть другие простые решения, готов выслушать.

Comment: Каждая чужая окружность вырезает в полуинтервале *[0, 2pi)* кусок (два куска) куда нельзя попадать. Соберите все такие куски в виде интервалов. Постройте их объединение - это задача на объединение отрезков на прямой. Дополнение этого объединения - набор интервалов. Теперь задача - кинуть случайную точку в набор интервалов. Для этого интервалы собирают в один общий интервал (удаляют промежутки), кидают случайную точку туда, восстанавливают номер интервала и положение точки (угла) в нем. Восстанавливают точку на окружности из угла. Сложность алгоритма *NlogN*, *N* - число окружностей.

Comment: Random.insideUnitCircle.normalized - это зря. Достаточно строить случайную точку *a* на отрезке *[0, 2pi)* и отображать её в *(cos a, sin a)*.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy , Это сложно, но я кажется понял, что именно нужно сделать. А о вашем варианте получения точки на окружности не задумывался, круто. Получается сильно быстрее моего варианта?
Большое спасибо за ответ. Еще отпишу и поблагодарю, как реализую в коде =)

Comment: `NlogN` значит что тысячу окружностей вы обработаете мгновенно. Я не знаю сколько вам надо. Можно и миллионы. Сколько в память поместится.